# Excel Sorting "mixed data"

Tags: excel, sorting

I have 3 columns of data that need sorting into a specific order. The column to sort on are alpha numberics but contain letters and numbers. The best I can do using the standard Excel sort function on the ribbon bar is:

[image]

Ideally the output should be:

[image]

AS you can see the Excel sort function isn't doing the job I want it to!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 3 Custom lists in Excel Data Sort!

```
List 1
pre-dose
1h
1h30min
2h
30min
3h
4h
6h
8h
12h
16h
24h
36h
48h
72h
96h
120h
144h
168h
216h
264h
312h
384h
456h
528h
600h
672h
```

```
List2
Day -1
Day 1
Day 2
Day 14
Day 15
Day 16
Day 17
Day 18
Day 19
Day 20
Day 21
Day 23
Day 25
Day 27
Day 30
Day 33
Day 36
Day 39
Day 42
ESV
```

```
List 3
Sample 1
Sample 2
Sample 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Well Excel sort in fact does it's job of sorting numbers or letters but how it supposed know

Pre-doze should come before 30-min and after 24hr. What's the logic for Pre-Doze

The best solution I see is to use VBA. This way you can have full control over your logic.

There are many sorting scripts are over the internet, but since you have a multidimensional array this solution may get complicated.

Comment: Actually I found the answer!! I created 3 Custom lists in Excel Data Sort